# Change BP Avatar through WP_REST_API

Tags: wordpress-rest-api, buddypress

I’m currently extending the wp rest API to centralize everything and be able to move from an webapp to a real app
(I litteraly only miss the Update and delete of the avatar + social login to complete the API)

I’ve been through a lot and learned many things through this job, but I’ve just passed a day without succeeding in uploading and avatar through the API, thus making no progress

I get a “true” value from this : `bp_core_avatar_handle_upload($_FILES['avatar'],'xprofile_avatar_upload_dir');` 
but nothing else happens (not even an upload)

I’m still trying to find my way through, but I’d like an helping hand on this one

Thx

EDIT: 
Since I couldn't make it work and the avatar is picked based on the last update of a '-bp-full' and '-bp-thumb' file, I'll just put the file in the /uploads/avatars/{id}/

Now I'm trying to understand how to resize to make the thumbnail
My current code looks like this

```
$file = $_FILES['file'];
        $file_meta = getimagesize($file["tmp_name"]);
        if($file_meta !== false){

          if($file_meta[0] == $file_meta[1]){

            $file_path = $file['tmp_name'];
            $FILE_EXTENSION = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

            // use 'avatar-bp....' instead of default wp_hash($file['name'].time())
            // to avoid having multiple image for each user
            $full_filename  = 'avatar-bpfull.'  . $FILE_EXTENSION;
            $thumb_filename = 'avatar-bpthumb.' . $FILE_EXTENSION;
            $target_dir = wp_get_upload_dir()['basedir'].'/avatars/'.$user_id.'/';

            for($i = 0; $i++; $i<=1){
              if($i == 0){
                $width = 150;
              }else{
                $width = 80;
              }

              $height = $width;

              $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
              $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($file_path);
              imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width_orig, $height_orig);
              if($i==0){
                $image_full = $image_p;
              }else{
                $image_thumb = $image_p;
              }
            }
            return $image_full;

            // move from /tmp
            if (rename($file_path, $target_dir.$thumb_filename) && rename($file_path, $target_dir.$full_filename)) {
                return "The file has been uploaded.";
            } else {
                return "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
            }
          }else{
            return 'not a squared image';
          }
        }else{
          return 'not an image';
        }
```

Am I doing something wrong ? Is there some best practice I should follow ?
Thx :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone needs to do the same, you need to know 2 things:

1. buddypress store images in uploads/avatars/{user_id}
2. buddypress select images based on 'last_modification' file meta

So if you don't get how to user the bp_core_avatar_handle_upload function, here's my work around :
(my script is supposed to receive only squared image as shown by 'if($file_meta[0] == $file_meta[1])', take it out if you need )

```
$image_full;
$file = $_FILES['file'];
$file_path = $file['tmp_name'];
$file_meta = getimagesize($file_path);

if($file_meta !== false){

  if($file_meta[0] == $file_meta[1]){
    // use 'avatar-bp....' instead of default wp_hash($file['name'].time())
    // to avoid having multiple image for each user
    $full_filename  = 'avatar-bpfull.'  . $FILE_EXTENSION;
    $thumb_filename = 'avatar-bpthumb.' . $FILE_EXTENSION;
    $target_dir = wp_get_upload_dir()['basedir'].'/avatars/'.$user_id.'/';

    $source = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($file_path)); // La photo est la source

    $full = imagecreatetruecolor(150, 150);
    $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor(80, 80);

    imagecopyresampled($full, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($full), imagesy($full), imagesx($source), imagesy($source));
    imagecopyresampled($thumb, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($thumb), imagesy($thumb), imagesx($source), imagesy($source));

    if(imagejpeg($thumb, $target_dir.$thumb_filename.'jpeg') && imagejpeg($full, $target_dir.$full_filename.'jpeg')){
      return "The file has been uploaded.";
    } else {
      return "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
  }else{
    return 'not a squared image';
  }
}else{
  return 'not an image';
}
```